# Should we have a canonical question tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I posted a canonical question and was wondering why there wasn't a tag for canonical questions?

Shouldn't we have a tag for this? Right now the only way to know for sure that the question is intended to be canonical is if the OP mentions it. I don't believe we have a list of *all* canonical questions either.

So - do you believe we should have a tag for canonical questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me address the two things in here.

First, we don't really want a list of canonical questions, too hard to maintain as mentioned in previous meta-post [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/should-we-work-harder-to-create-canonical-questions) and [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/would-it-make-sense-to-have-a-curated-list-of-canonical-questions).

Second, [tags are meant](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to regroup question about a particular topic. 'canonical questions' are not a security topic, at best it is a meta-topic.

I am therefore strongly opposed to this.

Nevertheless, I'd support the creation of a meta question on 'how to  write/answer a canonical question'. This should include information like, when should we write a CQ, what should be included in my CQ (info banner for example, references, related meta-post).

Comment: Perhaps we make a tag-wiki for the "vulnerabilities" tag then? As Gilles suggested in the post you linked.

Comment: [tag:vulnerability] does exist already. It just will need an edit.

Comment: That is what I meant sorry :D